# Overrule numeric-comp sorting for one \cite command

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I am using biblatex with the numeric-comp citation style, which sorts&compresses citations.
E.g. `\cite{C,A,E,B} ... \cite{D}` becomes "[1-3,5] ... [4]" (with 1=A, 2=B, 3=C, 4=D and 5=E).

In general this suits me fine, however there is one citation in my document where I would like biblatex to respect the order in which I specify the references. E.g. `\cite{C,A,E,B}` should become "[3,1,5,2]".

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use (e.g.) `\cites{C}{A}{E}{B}` for the "special" citation. See section 3.6.3 of the `biblatex` manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{C03,A01,B02}.

Some text \cites{C03}{A01}{B02}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]